# Get the output result of a process with java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to execute a process for some time and then get the output and destroy the process. This is my code

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader temp;
p.waitFor(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
temp=stdInput;
p.destroy(); 
System.out.println(temp.readLine());
```

but I get as result

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

How can I copy the result after executing the process 7 seconds? If I use this code

```
p.waitFor(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
while ((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
    Helper.log(inputRead);
}
```

the while loop will never terminate because the process is still alive after the `waitFor`, so I have to destroy it. And If I destroy the process I am not able to get the content of `stdInput` anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want that call to `waitFor()` since it waits until the process is destroyed. You also don't want to read for as long as the `InputStream` is open, since such a read would terminate only when the process is killed.

Instead, you can simply start the process, and then wait for 7 seconds. Once 7 seconds have passed, read the available data in the buffer without waiting for the stream to close:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
Thread.sleep(7000); //Sleep for 7 seconds
while (stdInput.ready()) { //While there's something in the buffer
     //read & print - replace with a buffered read (into an array) if the output doesn't contain CR/LF
    System.out.println(stdInput.readLine()); 
}
p.destroy(); //The buffer is now empty, kill the process.
```

If the process keeps printing, so `stdInput.ready()` always returns true you can try something like this:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
char[] buffer = new char[16 * 1024]; // 16 KiB buffer, change size if needed
long startedReadingAt = System.currentTimeMillis(); //When did we start reading?
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startedReadingAt < 7000) { //While we're waiting
    if (stdInput.ready()){
        int charsRead = stdInput.read(buffer); //read into the buffer - don't use readLine() so we don't wait for a CR/LF
        System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, charsRead));  //print the content we've read
    } else {
        Thread.sleep(100); // Wait for a while before we try again
    }
}
p.destroy(); //Kill the process
```

In this solution, instead of sleeping, the thread spends the next 7 seconds reading from the `InputStream`, then it closes the process.

Comment: readLine() is not enough ? 
you think that ready() may return false when readLine() returns  true ?

Comment: the while loop will never terminate because there will be always something to read in the buffer until the process stops

Comment: `p.waitFor(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` blocks the thread for `7` seconds or until the process terminates so there is no need to replace that call with `Thread.sleep(7000);`.

Comment: @Titus I'm not calling `p.waitFor()` since that would block forever (until the process is destroyed)!

Comment: I know you're not calling `p.waitFor()` but you've replaced `p.waitFor(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` with `Thread.sleep(7000);` which is unnecessary.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the process doesn't terminate by itself and the program never exits the `while` loop.

Comment: @davidxxx If I recall correctly, `readLine()` blocks until it finds a line or until the stream is closed.

Comment: @sonia If the process is always writing, and `ready()` always returns true, you'll need to limit the reads according to the number of bytes read

Comment: it means there is no solution for reading the output generated in the first 7 seconds, I can only read some data without knowing if it was generated in the first 7 seconds or not ?

Comment: @sonia There's always a solution. I proposed another approach in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked perfectly ! However I tried it with stdInput.readLine(); instead of using a buffer and it worked also fine :)

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.IOException: Stream closed` That is probably because you're calling `temp.readLine()` after `p.destroy()`.

The problem seems to be that the process doesn't add a new line termination after the part that you want to retrieve. To fix that, you can read the output from the program in small chunks instead of line by line.

Here is an example:

```
try(InputStream is = p.getInputStream()){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    String content = "";
    for(int r = 0; (r = is.read(buffer))!=-1;){
        content+=new String(buffer, 0, r);
        if(content.equals("all content")){// check if all the necessary data was retrieved.
            p.destroy();
            break;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you know the exact format of the program's output, a better solution will be to use a scanner.

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getInputStream())){
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        String word = sc.next();
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The example above will read the program's output one word at a time.

From your comments it seems that the problem is that the process never terminates by itself and your program never exits the `while` loop.

To fix that, you can use a timer to destroy the process after a period of time, here is an example:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        p.destroy();
        t.cancel();
        t.purge();
    }
}, 7000);

try(BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));){
    while ((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
        ...
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Keep in mind that this approach will always cause `stdInput.readLine()` to throw an exception.

Comment: The problem isn't the newline, it's the fact that he reads the `InputStream` for as long as it's open, which is until the process is killed. Also, he might not know what `all content` is. OP just tries to read whatever the process printed out during those 7 seconds.

Comment: I tried your code, it never terminates if the process don't return any output. It also return java.io.IOException: Stream closed if the process return some output